# Printing from PDF changes orientation

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-reader, orientation

From Acrobat Reader, each page looks like they are in portrait mode, 
but when I actually print the document, some documents are printed upsidedown and some are in landscape mode.

Is there a way to prevent this so that I can print as exactly shown in Acrobat reader?

Comment: Can we assume you're talking about reader for windows?

Comment: @Josheph: Yes, you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the print dialog, uncheck **Auto-Rotate and Center**. This will stop Reader from trying to adjust the print:

[image]